# comparar y copiar buscarv en excel

Tags: excel

tengo un excel con 2 pestañas en una esta el codigo y precio (tabla1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en otra mas larga tengo pestaña con codigo y tarifa(tabla12

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debo utilizar la formula **buscarv** en (tabla2) y la columna codigo que coincida con la (tabla1) debo insertar el precio en (tabla1)

estaba intentando hacerlo con esta formula pero me da error:

```
=BUSCARV($A1; tabla1; COLUMNA(tabla2!B$1))
```

Comment: Prueba con algo parecido a esto `=BUSCARV(Hoja1!A2;Hoja2!$A$2:$B$5;2)`. Donde Hoja1 seria tabla1 y Hoja2 seria Tabla2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto: =BUSCARV($A2;RANGO;9;FALSO). $A2 es la celda que quieres, RANGO es el rango donde buscar de la segunda pestaña, 9 es la columna del RANGO. Tiene que definir el rango en la segunda pestaña antes de aplicar la fórmula.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El falso es para que el codigo se exacto y si le pone VERDADERO enntonces busca parecidos, el dos es para que me de el resultado de la columna 2 en la matriz que seleccione, tambien seria bueno que el D2:E14 lo fije seleccionando esa parte y tecleando F4 para que quede $D$4:$E$14, asi cuando ud corre hacia abajo la formula la matriz no se le va a correr, A2 si debe quedar suelto